# How do you schedule a rundeck job to stop or restart periodically?

Tags: rundeck

I have a number of jobs that run 24/7. I would like to cycle them every weekend to flush caches, sticky sessions, connection pools, do maintenance, etc

In the job definition I see the ability to schedule a job to run at a certain time but no way to set it to die gracefully at a certain time. 
That would be super useful.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer for [Need to configure the job level timeout option for rundeck Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091650/need-to-configure-the-job-level-timeout-option-for-rundeck-job)

As 2.7 Rundeck support 
[Job Timeout](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#timeout)

> **Timeout**
>   You can set a maximum runtime for a job. If the runtime exceeds this value, the job will be halted (as if a user had killed it.) (Note: Timeout only affects the job if is invoked directly, not if it is used as a Job Reference.)

[image]

> But will it restart immediately afterwards or will it stay halted? I
>   want it to start again.

Combine Timeout and [Retry](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#retry), you should be able to achieve, restart after the timeout
[image]

Comment: But will it restart immediately afterwards or will it stay halted? I want it to start again.

Comment: @mwielbut job timeout will not make the job restart, it will make the job as failed. You can write some bash/python script to check if there is a job running and put it in your crontab,if not start the job using Rundeck API http://rundeck.org/docs/man1/index.html

Comment: It seems that Rundeck provides a "Retry" option, combine with "Timeout" it may solve your problem.