# Need to configure the job level timeout option for rundeck Job

Tags: rundeck

I am using rundeck 1.6 version and need to configure timeout option for the rundeck jobs so that when the job exceeds the timeout value, it automatically stops without going to the next step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As 2.7 Rundeck support 
[Job Timeout](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#timeout)

> **Timeout**
>   You can set a maximum runtime for a job. If the runtime exceeds this value, the job will be halted (as if a user had killed it.) (Note: Timeout only affects the job if is invoked directly, not if it is used as a Job Reference.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On server from Rundeck installed, alter the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config to:

Host *

ServerAliveInterval 180
ServerAliveCountMax 2